# Getting WriteTimeoutException running cassandra-stress, "Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE"

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to run the stress test using Cassandra in Centos VMWare virtual machine, but hit with the below command timeout frequently if I increase the number of rows to more than 200000
"com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)"

I have 800 GB pmem size in my VM.
Command used: Cassandra-stress user profile=cqlstress-insanity-example.yaml ops\(insert=1\) no-warmup cl=ONE n=200000 -mode native cql3 -pop seq=1..200000 -rate threads=33 |& stdbuf -o0 tee -a /cassandra_log

Version Used: Casandra 4.0

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what question you're asking so I'm going to assume that you think there's a problem with `cassandra-stress`.

When you run `cassandra-stress`, the idea is to push your cluster to its limit. Based on your testing, what you have identified is the maximum operations your cluster can handle.

That isn't a bad thing. The utility is working as advertised. Cheers!